# Grep: return matching line plus the following N lines up to a certain character?

Tags: bash, grep, fasta

I have a text file that is consistently formatted like this:

```
>keyword1 keyword2 keyword3
somedata
somedata
somedata
>keyword4 keyword5 keyword6
somedata
somedata
>keyword7 keyword8
somedata
somedata
somedata
somedata
....
```

That is, an annotation line that always starts with ">" followed by a variable number of lines of data.

I'd like to grep for something in the lines that start ">" and return all the lines of data that follow. If there were always, say, 4 lines of data after, I could do `grep -A 4 '^>' keyword` but I don't know how to account for the variation.

To give an example, if the file was this:

```
>tomato lettuce cucumber
123
456
>apple banana
111
222
333
>tomato
444
5757
558585
```

I want to be able to do something grep-like with "tomato" and get back:

```
>tomato lettuce cucumber
123
456
>tomato
444
5757
558585
```

Comment: If you are describing FASTA format, why don't you say so? There are ready-made tools for this sort of thing.

Comment: Because I want to expand my knowledge of bash tools. I already wrote a python script that will do this, but I could tell it was overkill.

Comment: Using topical keywords also makes it easier for others to find this discussion in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk one-liner:

```
kent$  awk '/^>/{t=/tomato/?7:0}t' file  
>tomato lettuce cucumber
123
456
>tomato
444
5757
558585
```

Comment: Bingo. What does the '?7:0' do?

Comment: `boolean? a:b` if boolean is true, take a otherwise b @user2063292

Comment: The thing that threw me as well was that you used `7` rather than the more conventional `1`. Added to that, I'm not sure why you didn't just do `{t=/tomato/}`. @user2063292 if `t` is set to a non-zero value, awk will do the default action, which prints the line.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using awk:

```
awk -v RS='>'  '/tomato/ {printf(">%s",$0)}' file
>tomato lettuce cucumber
123
456
>tomato
444
5757
558585
```

This changes the record separator `RS` from the default newline to ">". If the record contains the word you're interested in, print it.

If you are dealing with FASTA data, you have other options, such as the `Bio::SeqIO` module in BioPerl.